# Open cursor for select statement with Input variables

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, cursor, package

I have two cursors in my package. the first Cursor does not have an input parameter so I have Successfully Opened it like this:

```
OPEN c1 for
       SELECT foracid,
         acct_name,
         addr_1,
         addr_2,
         sol_desc,
         city_code,
         gam.FUTURE_UN_CLR_BAL_AMT
       FROM tbaadm.gam,
         tbaadm.sol
       WHERE gam.sol_id   = sol.sol_id
         AND schm_type     IN ('CAA','ODA','LAA')
         AND schm_code NOT IN ('CTSTF');
     CLOSE c1;
```

But My second Cursor has an input Parameter and I can't do:

```
 OPEN c2 (vMyName varchar2) for select .....
```

because of this error:

```
Found Varhcar2 Expecting : ) and -or...
```

Can I really Open This cursor this way or what should I do?

Comment: Man That is in German Or Something :(

Comment: Yeah Sorry, my fault... but I don't think it's helping you with the particular problem anyways... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the following:

```
create or replace procedure proc (c2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

vMyName varchar2(100);

begin
  vMyName := 'Some Value';

  open c2 for
    select col1, col2, col3
    from tab1
    where val = vMyName;
end;
```

Comment: Parameter `c2` should be an OUT variable. `c2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`.